# Sales calls being posted to chatter

Tags: salesforce1-app

When I log an event or call it is automatically bringing posted on chatter. How do I stop this?

Comment: Are you doing the action from the publisher? Actions done in the publisher show up in the chatter feed. You could remove this publisher action and force people to use the related list buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off Chatter for Tasks/Events in the Chatter -> Feed Tracking section of setup.